# Unhandled Exception - Access violation if /SUBSYSTEM parameter is changed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, linker

I have an application, in which I use a `console` to see some of the values being output. Now some of the requirements have changed, and I do not need the `console` during runtime anymore.

I tried to change that, by toggling the `/SUBSYSTEM` parameter, found under `Project Properties->Linker->System->Subsystem` from `Console` to `Windows`, as I'd done the same for an earlier thing, and it had worked.

On this occasion, it gives me an Unhandled Exception, in `mfc110u.dll`, as the object cannot be instantiated.

Why does this exception occur, and how else can I turn off the `console` with the running program? I'm using `VS2012` as the dev environment.

Comment: In my experience, when you get exceptions in mfc110u.dll, the error is generated somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure it's not in `MFC`, the project works fine, if the Subsystem parameter is 'Console', but does not work, if I change it to 'Windows'. I'd like to know what, if anything, could cause this. From what I read, this affects the entry point of the program, and the same is reflected in the DLL, as the object does not get instantiated. So what is to be done..

Comment: Just use the debuger! You can even debug release programs

Comment: Yes, well, that's the problem. It compiles, but the run fails, as there is an unhandled exception, because an object is not being instantiated. `MFC` fails it in the `CreateInstance()` call, or thereabouts. It might be something incredibly silly, but I do not want the console to come up when the application runs. I'd brought up the console once, with another application, by toggling the parameter from `Windows` to `Console`. I thought the same could work in reverse if I didn't want it. But it gives the unhandled exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want a console, declare a winmain.  This is the non-unicode version

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main (int, char**);

// If we just start with main, we will always get a console window
int WINAPI WinMain (
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow
) 
{
    int argc = __argc;
    char** argv = __argv;
#ifdef DEBUG
  // If we are running in debug mode, open a console window
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("conin$", "r", stdin);
    freopen("conout$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("conout$", "w", stderr);
#endif

    return main (argc, argv);
}

int main (
    int argc,
    char** argv
)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Whoo hoo", "It Works!!!", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should be the solution: Windows programs have different entry point, called WinMain. If you use a FrameWork, like MFC, this is nested somewhere.

Comment: Ah, OK. I hadn't understood the mechanism of this. Got it now. Thanks a lot.